# How to use a util classes in a static context in multi modules project?

Tags: java

I am having an issue in using a class in a multi module project:

I have a multi module project with a util modules like this: HighLevelProject -> CoreProject -> UtilProject

In UtilProject I have this code :

```
public interface UrlFactory
{
    URL getUrl(String url) throws Exception;

    HttpClient getClient();
}
```

In CoreProject I have this code with the dependency to the UtilProject:

```
import com.utilProject.UrlFactory;
public class RespUrlFactory implements UrlFactory {
    public static UrlFactory resp = null;

    @Override
    public URL getUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        return resp(url);
    }

    @Override
    public HttpClient getClient() {
        return resp();
    }
```

And in the HighLevelProject I have this code:

```
    import com.coreProject.RespLinkFactory;
    import com.utilProject.UrlFactory;

    public static void setLinkFactory() {
        RespUrlFactory.resp = new UrlFactory() {
            @Override
            public URL getUrl(String url) throws Exception {
                return new URL(url);
            } 
@Override
public HttpClient getClient() {
    return resp();
}}
```

At this "HighLevelProject" on this line "RespUrlFactory.resp = new UrlFactory()" I have the next error when building the project:

```
error: incompatible types: <anonymous com.utilProject.UrlFactory> cannot be converted to com.coreProject.UrlFactory
        RespUrlFactory.resp = new UrlFactory() {
```

Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your actual code as a [mcve]. Your second code block here is not valid. `resp(url)` and `resp()` aren't valid methods and `RespUrlFactory.delegate` isn't defined

Comment: In any case, the problem seems to be that you've not implemented the getClient method, which your IDE should be telling you before you try to build the project on your own

Comment: `new UrlFactory() { … }` is an object which is a UrlFactory, but it is not a RespUrlFactory.  You would need to use `new RespUrlFactory` for that, or change the type of `delegate` from RespUrlFactory to UrlFactory.

Comment: Strange.  It appears that you have two definitions for `UrlFactory`, one defined in the `com.coreProject` package and one defined in the `com.utilProject` package.  The problem is that you're creating an instance of one of these types and are then trying to assign it to a variable that is one of the other type.

Comment: @CryptoFool There was no definition of the `delegate` field in the question, so how do you know what its type is?  (An edit has been made which clarifies this by removing the assignment of `delegate` entirely, so the question is now moot.)

Comment: @VGR - from the error message, which mentions both of the UrlFactory types.

Comment: @VGR - wacky that the code has changed out from under us.  The name changed, but it is still true that what is being assigned to, now the `resp` property of a `RespUrlFactory`, not a `RespUrlFactory`, is a `UrlFactory`.  The problem, apparently is that `UrlFactory` being instantiated is a DIFFERENT `UrlFactory`.  Read the error message carefully.

Comment: @CryptoFool Ah yes, I see what you mean now.  Two different UrlFactory classes in different packages.

Comment: It’s true that the error says that I’m using different UrlFactory, but i have just one UrlFactory in utilProject @VGR

Comment: @Falvius I didn't read all the comments, but I would like to answer your question with another question. How do you use external libraries in multiple modules? Now, my actual answer: You could build a library with your utility classes and import that library to the modules that need it. That might be one way to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are defining two different `UrlFactory` interfaces, one in `com.utilProject` and one in `com.coreProject`.  I'm getting this directly from the error message:

> incompatible types: <anonymous com.utilProject.UrlFactory> cannot be converted to com.coreProject.UrlFactory
> RespUrlFactory.resp = new UrlFactory() {

Where is `com.coreProject.UrlFactory` defined?  The Java compiler is saying that it exists, so it must be defined somewhere.  That's the core (no pun intended) problem here.  There may be other issues with this code, but this is the initial mystery to be solved.

Did you maybe mean to move the definition of `UrlFactory` from one package to another, but instead copied it?  OR, could this be a build problem?  Might there be a stale `.class` file lying around or something like that.  Was `UrlFactory` ever in the `com.coreProject` package?

UPDATE: For yucks, why don't you try renaming the UrlFactory interface that you can see.  I'm curious if the names of both types will change, or just the one in `com.utilProject`.  This will tell you something either way.

Comment: Indeed you are right. Somehow in the building process of the multi modules project, the order of building was wrong. 

In the first step, the UrlFactory was in the coreProject, i moved it and in the building process it was not build in the util project.